# Help me with My Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server

In this procedure, I want to delete those number which coming in @msisdn from Master Table and insert into tblDeactive:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[msisdn_deactivition](@msisdn  varchar(1024))
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

    insert into tblDeactive SELECT *  from msisdn_master where msisdn in (@msisdn);
    delete from msisdn_master where msisdn in (@msisdn);

END
```

...but it does not work?

Answer (score 3):

You can't use a single query parameter in place of a list of values.  One parameter = one value.

See [Parameterize an SQL IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-a-sql-in-clause) for several solutions and lots of discussion about using parameters with the `IN( )` predicate.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a split function, that will split your delimitted @msisdn into a table to select from.

Have a look at this link

[How to pass a list of values or array to SQL Server stored procedure?](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/passing_arrays_to_stored_procedures.htm)

Answer (score 1):

`IN` in TSQL needs to take multiple arguments per item. At the moment, if you pass it "123,456,789", it is looking for the *single* row with value "123,456,789". It **isn't** looking for "123", "456" or "789".

Look for something like a split udf - plenty on the internet. This takes your delimited string and returns a column of values. Typically you then *join* the the udf results (rather than use `IN`).

**DON'T** use `EXEC` here, as you shouldn't trust the input.